# Divine Fury static damage round up or down?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature

I have a new level 3 Zealot Barbarian and I am wondering about the wording of the feature Divine Fury.

> **Divine Fury** (XGtE, page 11)
>
> Starting when you choose this path at 3rd level, you can channel divine fury into your weapon strikes. While you're raging, the first creature you hit on each of your turns with a weapon attack takes extra damage equal to 1d6 + half your barbarian level. The extra damage is necrotic or radiant; you choose the type of damage when you gain this feature.

Would the static "half your barbarian level" round down as most things do that are not specified when at an odd level?

I suspect it does but I would like some clarification per RAW.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Divine Fury's damage is rounded down

Unless stated otherwise, you always round down. From the [basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/introduction#RoundDown) (or PHB p. 7):

> Whenever you divide a number in the game, round down if you end up with a fraction, even if the fraction is one-half or greater.

An example of an exception is something like the wizard's [Arcane Recovery](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/wizard#ArcaneRecovery-411) (PHB p. 115, emphasis mine):

> The spell slots can have a combined level that is equal to or less than half your wizard level **(rounded up)**

Since Divine Fury does not explicitly say it rounds up, it rounds down as usual.

Comment: Another important "round up": the increase of maximum hit points when gaining a level, if using "average hit points" instead of rolling.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you always round down when not specifically told otherwise.  Page 7 of the PHB says:

> Whenever you divide a number in the game, round down if you end up with a fraction, even if the fraction is one-half or greater.

Comment: I couldn't find that in the PHB. I was looking in the wrong area.